# iTunes Connect keywords

Tags: app-store-connect, itunes-store

Can anyone offer any color on how the keywords work on ITC's app store? In the bad old days, you needed to be careful to separately list things, so that:

```
Toronto real estate,Vancouver real estate
```

was bad, whereas:

```
Toronto,Vancouver,real estate
```

was better. Any hints or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, that has changed completely as of late. It is a long answer and I would suggest going into specialized websites. As a small rule: the words forming a sentence in the title count "The Best App" will be more easily found with that sentence in the search field than having "the,best,app" in the keywords. In-app texts counted: no more. Keywords count separately so "Vancouver City" as keywords would have the same effect as "Vancouver,city" but in the last case you have "three" keywords instead of one (Vancouver, Vancouver city and City).

Comment: This is useful. Can you point me to one of those web sites?

Comment: I'll post this as an answer with a great link I have just found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way keywords are managed by Apple changes from time to time.

I would suggest going into specialized websites. A rather simplistic rule is: sentences in the title counts towards searches: if a user searches for "great party", then an app that has the exact "great party" in the title will appear before an app that doesn't have that exact sentence (e.g. "Creating a great party" would appear before "Great aunt party"). This also applies to keywords (e.g. "Creating a great party" would appear first with the same search compared to an app having "great,party" in the keywords).

In-app texts counted: no more. Keywords count separately so "Vancouver City" as keyword would have the same effect as "Vancouver,city" but in the last case you have "three" keywords instead of one (Vancouver, Vancouver city and City -well, and City Vancouver, but that is less probably looked for).

The more keywords you can place in the title, the better (you'll have more space in the keywords section) but Apple may reject your app for that reason (I have experience with that). However, this depends on the reviewer and the risks you are able to take, in terms of time. You may see an example of an app title with plenty of keywords in the title [here](https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/fisheye-fisheye-camera-old/id569723994?mt=8) (notice they didn't use that bunch of keywords inside the title [in the English title](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fisheye-fisheye-camera-old/id569723994?mt=8)).

Finally, this is a link that gets updated and also links to the most well-known App Store Optimization websites: [apptamin](http://www.apptamin.com/blog/app-store-optimization-aso-app-name-and-keywords).